# How to connect to Ethereum instances using AWS Ethereum blockchain templates?

Tags: amazon-web-services, blockchain, ethereum

Have tried to connect to the EC2 instances using putty for the Ethereum fabric by setting up Bastion host.
Now need to know how to upload smart contracts, initiate transactions.
How to view the Ethexplorer/ Ethstats in the browser?
Facing issue in opening the Ethexplorer/ ethstats in browser - the host is not found.
Is there any docs that will be helpful? Couldn't find any docs regarding the same.
Thanks,
Deepak.